# How to give column gap on desktop and mobile devices using bootstrap 4 only?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to give a gap of 15px between two rows and two columns. I don't know how to give the gaps on desktop and mobile devices using bootstrap only. There is something to do with margins but don't know the ideal way to do it.

For the 2nd row, I have two columns that will be displayed side by side on greater than tablet devices and it will display one below the other on mobile devices.
I am getting difficulty in setting the gaps in the mobile devices only.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Gap</title>
  <link 
   rel="stylesheet"         
   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
   integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
   crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 p-3" style="
        background-color: #f8d7da;
        color: #721c24;
        border: 1px solid #f5c6cb;
      ">
        B
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 p-3" style="
        color: #004085;
        background-color: #cce5ff;
        border: 1px solid #b8daff;
      ">
        A
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 p-3" style="
        color: #004085;
        background-color: #cce5ff;
        border: 1px solid #b8daff;
      ">
        C
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need can be achieved very easily with a slight modification in B4. In that version, adding any margin to the `columns` breaks the layout completely. The workaround is to not add a margin to it, but an inner enclosing div. Which works the same. Your code thereby becomes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Gap</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container mt-5">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-12 p-3" style="background-color: #f8d7da; color: #721c24; border: 1px solid #f5c6cb;">
                    B
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 px-0">
                    <div class="inner p-3 mb-3 mb-sm-0 mr-sm-3" style="color: #004085; background-color: #cce5ff; border: 1px solid #b8daff;">
                        A
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 px-0">
                    <div class="inner p-3" style="color: #004085; background-color: #cce5ff; border: 1px solid #b8daff;">
                        C
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](http://%20%20%20%20https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/e5ro0kLt/7/)

The same can be done very easily using `g-*` classes on the `row` in B5.

Edit: You should also keep in mind that `*-3` in Bootstrap is by default 16px. There is nothing (by default) here which will give you 15px. You'll need to add a custom class, OR if you're using SASS, you can add another value like `15` (with value 15px) to the margin utility in Bootstrap, which will give you something like `mb-15` that will be equivalent to `margin-bottom: 15px;`. [Utilities API](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/api/#add-utilities)

Answer (score 1):

To make the gap appear on the mobile devices use `mb-4 mr-4`, and if you want to hide the gaps on larger screens use `mb-md-0 mr-md-0`or any other breakpoint you want.

Comment: Thanks!! for 2nd row I need a horizontal gap in desktop and vertical gap in mobile

Comment: To show horizontal gap only on desktop `mr-0 mr-lg-4`, and to show the vertical gap only on mobile `mr-4 mr-lg-0`. Combine both to get your desired behavior. And I'm assuming that by desktop you mean `lg` breakpoint.

Comment: could you share the example of your solution? I did tried that but did not get the desired result.

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake in my comment, vertical gap classes should be `mb-4 mb-lg-0` https://jsfiddle.net/mwrpLc8z/9/

Comment: the example you showed is not working with grid layout. Yes it is working correctly with two different divs.

Comment: Wight grid layout use padding not margin. So it will be `pr-0 pr-lg-4` and `pb-4 pb-lg-0`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is an effective way. Basically, I just add `margin-bottom` to `container B` and add `margin-top` to `container A & C`. Then, I use `flex` for the two columns. Instead of using margin, I use an empty container for the gap. The disadvantage is it's not exactly `15px.

References:

1. [Bootstrap - Flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)
2. [Box Model, inc. Margin](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)
3. [Bootstrap - Spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Gap</title>
  <link 
   rel="stylesheet"         
   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
   integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
   crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 p-3 mb-4" style="
        background-color: #f8d7da;
        color: #721c24;
        border: 1px solid #f5c6cb;
      ">
        B
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-sm-between mt-2">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm p-3" style="
        color: #004085;
        background-color: #cce5ff;
        border: 1px solid #b8daff;
      ">
        A
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-1 p-3">
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm p-3" style="
        color: #004085;
        background-color: #cce5ff;
        border: 1px solid #b8daff;
      ">
        C
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```